# How to get id in dropdown and also set default value on top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the code below and I want *card_id* but it shows *null*.  How can I get the *id* and *is_default* card on top? when I use ng-click, it shows the result below. I want to get the selected card_id.

```
<select ng-model="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.card_id" >
    <option ng-value="item.card_id"  
        ng-repeat="item in approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards" 
        ng-selected="item.is_default">{{item.brand +'      '+ item.last_digits}}
    </option>
</select>
```

result:

```
card_id: "",
charge_description: "ff", 
charge_type: "Credit Card Payment"
```

Comment: You need to use `ng-options`

Comment: please explain i am new in angularjs ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) (that page has more examples) to set the options for the select list and [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) to display the *card_id* in the DOM. It also uses functional approach to set the currentcard using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). See the example below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.approvedinvoicesCtrl = {
      current_job: {
        cards: [{
          card_id: 1,
          brand: "BMW",
          last_digits: "Z3",
          is_default: false
        }, {
          card_id: 2,
          brand: "Mercedes",
          last_digits: "713",
          is_default: true
        }, {
          card_id: 3,
          brand: "Audi",
          last_digits: "Q4",
          is_default: false
        }]
      }
    };
    //set the model/default selected item
    $scope.approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard = $scope.approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards.find(CardIsDefault);
    $scope.log = function() {
      console.log('card_id: ', $scope.approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.card_id);
    };
  });

function CardIsDefault(card) {
  return card.is_default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>Selected brand: <span ng-bind="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.brand"></span>
  </div>
  <div>Selected Id: <span ng-bind="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.card_id"></span>
  </div>
  <select ng-options="item.brand+' '+item.last_digits for item in approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards" ng-model="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard"></select>
  <button ng-click="log();">show card_id</button>
</div>
```

Comment: when customer selected is_default 3 then ..? how to select automaically  is_default card true... not like this  .current_job.cards[1]

Comment: See my updated answer, which utilizes [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ng-init` and the `ng-options` directives:

```
<select ng-init="somethingHere = options[1]" 
        ng-model="somethingHere" 
        ng-options="option for option in options">
</select>
```

Use the `ng-init` to set the default value that you want

Comment: <select ng-init="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.card_id = item[1]" 
        ng-model="approvedinvoicesCtrl.currentcard.card_id" 
        ng-options="item for item in approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards">
</select>

Comment: something like ..?